# Выдает ошибку 500 и не понятно, в чем проблема

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

PHP:

```
<?php
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /eshop.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /eshop.com/index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

[image: Скриншот 1]

[image: Скриншот 2]

Comment: Так вроде `favicon.ico` это вообще неважное в разработке, ну короче это не значит, что сервер не будет работать.

Comment: Обновите страницу, пожалуйста, то же самое будет?

Comment: Дело не в этом. То что я должен написать после / в url должно записаться в переменную route в массиве get. Щас я напишу и покажу

Comment: В вопросе я добавил скрин ошибки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194836/21493925 не то?

Comment: сомневаюсь что это то что мне надо

Comment: а зачем вам первый rewriteRule про index ?

Comment: ну так у меня файл index.php

Comment: у вас дальнейшие правила и так проверяют что `!-f` не соответствуют реальному файлу, включая этот индекс.

Comment: Я только что решил проблему изменив .htaccess файл. Вот он:

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /eshop.com/
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]